# How to combine a single array of objects based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Utilizing javascript, I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
id |    date    | store |  type  | txn  | failed
------------------------------------------------
 1 |  10-02-18  |  32   |  short |  4   | false
 2 |  10-02-18  |  32   |  long  | null | true
 3 |  10-03-18  |  32   |  short |  7   | false
 4 |  10-03-18  |  32   |  long  |  10  | false
```

I want to be able to transform this array into something that looks like this:

```
[
 {
   date: 10-02-18,
   store: 32,
   short: {
     txn: 4,
     failed: false,
   },
   long: {
     txn: null,
     failed: true,
   },
 },
 {
   date: 10-03-18,
   store: 32,
   short: {
     txn: 7,
     failed: false,
   },
   long: {
     txn: 10,
     failed: true,
   },
 }
]
```

You can see I would like to combine the "type", "txn" and "failed" properties with row that have the same "date" and "storeId", adding the "type" as a property and "txn" and "failed" as child properties of the "type". The "id" property could be ignored in the new array.

I use lodash quite a bit but that isn't a requirement for this. I'm just struggling to wrap my head around how to do this transformation.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: please try by yourself first then and only then someone could help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to create an object with keys that represent something unique to the groups you want. You could make keys that are concatenations of `store_date` for example and the object will only have one of those and it will be quick to get if you have the store and date. You can build an object like this with reduce. Once you have the object, you can simply call `Object.values` to get the array of values. For example:

```js
let arr = [
    {id:1, date: "10-02-18",store: 32, type: "short", tx: 4, failed: false},
    {id:2, date: "10-02-18",store: 32, type: "long", tx: null, failed: true},
    {id:3, date: "10-03-18",store: 32, type: "short", tx: 7, failed: false},
    {id:4, date: "10-03-18",store: 32, type: "long ", tx: 10, failed: false}
]

let obj = arr.reduce((obj, {id, date, store, type, tx, failed}) => {
    // make a unique key
    key = `${date}_${store}`

    // if we haven't seen this key add it with the outline of the object
    if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = {date, store}

    // add specific type to either the found obj or the new one
    obj[key][type] = {tx, failed}
    return obj
}, {})

// obj is an object keyed to date_store
// get just the values
console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much!